# Assistance with Jquery AutoComplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a function that displays a list of people as a user types a LAN ID and that's working great. I now need the rest of the form to populate when the user clicks on the right person from the list or hits "enter" on that user's name in the list.  I'd like to do this without making a second Json call to the function in my MVC controller that contains the linq statement. Any suggestions or tips would be appreciated.

**Jquery**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#LanID_input").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetUserData")',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { lanID: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.FirstName + " " + item.LastName + "     " + item.LanID, value: item.LanID
                        };
                    }));
                },                  
            }); 
        },
      });
   });
```

Comment: *without making a second Json call* Why? You don't want to grab upfront all details a user can possibly request, do you? Also, I don't think this is a [linq] or [c#] question.

Comment: @GertArnold Removed the unncessary subject tags. I'd prefer not to make another call because my existing call already retrieves the fields. I'm not dealing with thousands of users where I can see it being better to make two calls.  Max users this look up and form population is dealing with is maybe 120 users.

Comment: Just save the other fields to an associative array (dictionary) with a key, then when they pick a row, look up the values with that key?